# Regex para verificar uma string

Tags: regex

Estou com dificuldades para criar uma regex, gostaria que ele identificasse `SP` ou `sp` ou `São paulo`, depois quaisquer outras palavras e novamente verificar se possui, `outro` ou `Minas gerais`(outros estados), nesta sequencia, exemplo que já montei :

```
(sp|SP|sao paulo|são paulo|São paulo)+.*(outro|mg|MG|pr|PR|Acre|ac|AC|Alagoas|AL|al|Amapa|APap|Amazonas|AM|am|Bahia|BA|ba|Ceará|ce|CE|Distrito Federal|DF|df|Espírito Santo|es|ES|Goias|GO|go|Maranhão|MA|ma|Mato Grosso|MT|mt|Mato Grosso do Sul|MS|ms|Minas Gerais|MG|mg|Pará|PA|pa|Paraiba|PB|pb|Parana|PR|pr|Pernambuco|PE|pe|Piaui|PI|pi|Rio de Janeiro|RJ|rj|Rio Grande do Norte|RN|rn|Rio Grande do Sul|RS|rs|Rondônia|RO|ro|Roraima|RR|rr|Santa Catarina|SC|sc|Sergipe|SE|se|Tocantins|TO|to)+
```

mas o `.*` acaba validando isso, e não é o que quero.

#### Exemplo para teste

> de sao paulo para outro estado
>   de sp para minas gerais
>   de São Paulo para mg

Comment: Tente trocar o `.*` por `.*?`

Comment: Pode dar exemplos de entrada junto com o que pretende capturar em cada uma?

Comment: A primeira parte casa "spSPsao paulo", isso está certo?

Comment: que verificar se ele digitou algo relacionado a sao paulo, por isso coloquei as variacoes, ja coloquei o .*?, mas nao funciona 100%

Comment: exemplo de entrada:
de sao paulo para outro estado;
de sp para minas gerais;
de São Paulo para mg

Comment: Consegue reproduzir no https://regex101.com/ esses exemplos? Busque incluir os que não estão funcionando também.

Comment: Estava testando la mesmo, fiz uns ajustes e a principio esta funcionando, Obrigado pela ajuda